# Laravel elequent grouping by joined (Inner join) fields with eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I want to achieve grouping on joined fields using Laravel's eloquent ORM with eager loading.

I have 2 models defined as follows:

```
class User extends Model{
  public $table = 'user';
  public function department(){
    return $this->belongsTo('models/Department','department_id','belongs_to_department_id');
  }
}
class Department extends Model{
  public $table = 'department'; 
}
```

I'm trying to join both the tables, and group by 'id' of department with eager loading

```
$User::with('department')->groupBy('department_id');
```

I'm getting error "department_id column not found".
I'm expecting to run the following MySql query:

```
select * from user inner join department inner join user.belongs_to_department_id=department.department_id group by department.department_id;
```

Comment: `$User::with(['department'=>function($query){
                $query->groupBy('department_id');
            } ])`. This should work.

Comment: Could you show us your `User` and `Department` schema?

Comment: You have an *extra* join it seems from the query that was produced: `join user.belongs_to_department_id=department.department_id`. This is where the bug is happening. I am pretty sure you don't have a `department_id` in your `department` table.

Comment: @Mozammil I have the department_id in department table.

Comment: Ah, could you show us the schema and, also, the relationship definition for `User` in Department?

Comment: @Mubin It doesn't work. I am getting department as null in the resulting JSON if I do groupBy

Comment: @Mozammil There is no relationship definition for User in Department, as I don't need it currently.

Comment: @DUDE_MXP can you show me your User and Department schema.